# Bootstrap Modal Won't open via function with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to open my Bootstrap modal via `Xmanage(param1, param2) function.

```
<input type='button'  value='Manage'  onclick='Xmanage($id, $projectName)'  class='btn btn-info'>


function Xmanage(id,projectName){
    $('#editModal').modal('show');    
}
```

But it doesn't open. On the other hand, if I try to call the `Xmanage()` without 
any parameters passed or involve, it worked.

```
function Xmanage(id,projectName){
        $('#editModal').modal('show');    
    }
```

Any clear explanations?
**UPDATE:**
This is where the `$id` and `$projectName` came from.

```
<?php
      $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * from tbl_project where col_status <> 2");
      $sql->execute();  
        while($result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
          $id           = $result['projectID'];
          $projectName  = $result['col_projName'];
          $date         = $result['col_createdDate'];
          $status       = ($result['col_status']==1) ? "checked" : "";
          echo " 
          <tr>
            <td>$id</td>
            <td>$projectName</td>
            <td>$date</td>
            <td>
            <input type='checkbox' valie='$id' data-size='mini' name='my-checkbox' $status>
            </td>
            <td>
            <div class='btn-group'  role='group'>
              <input type='button'  value='Manage'  onclick='Xmanage($id, $projectName)'  class='btn btn-info'>
              <input type='button'  value='Remove'  onclick='Xdelete($id)'                class='btn btn-danger'>
            </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          ";
        }
?>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Looked for errors on Chrome's Console.
Each time I click the Button, I received this error
`SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

And another thing is that, if I only pass `$id`, it works.
But if I added or pass the `$projectName` alone, it doesn't work.

Comment: Check the console for errors. Also, what are `$id` and `$projectName`, and where are they defined?

Comment: `<input type='button'  value='Manage'  onclick='Xmanage($id, $projectName)'  class='btn btn-info'>` I looped this code in a while loop. $id and $projectName are from the database.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I added the full php code for the looping.

Comment: Juju, are there any project with name containts special character like parenthesis () ?

Comment: Since you didn't include it: do you have the modal's markup somewhere on the page, with an `id="editModal"` attribute? I would also recommend including an example of the generated markup for the button.